# Invert relationship between units and plotted data Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to get my plot with Matplotlib to plot as a function of time. My problem is I want the plot to display results from the end of the data (1.6 seconds to 0 seconds) but I want the units on the bottom to go from 0 seconds to 1.6 seconds. How do I change the relationship between the plotted data and the x-axis?

I can't show the plot since I need more reputation to post images.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of   using `plt.plot(x, y)`, reverse the `x` values and use `plt.plot(x[::-1], y)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1.6, 100)
y = np.exp(-x*3)*x
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x[::-1], y)
plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using pyplot.

[image]

EDIT: To do what you want, you'll need to modify the plotting call:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Randy. The plot that you have there is similar to what I have now. My problem is I need the data to have the inverted axis like yours, but the actual numbers on the bottom to read 0, 0.5, 1.0 ect... left to right